# Problems with weak var and pointers between two classes

Tags: ios, swift, pointers, weak-references

I'm using Swift language.
I'm in my viewcontroller class, and I want to store something on another class, but I don't want that class to have any strong pointers to my class. So i'm using `weak`. I'm trying two ways to do this. One works (as in succeeds at not have a strong pointer to my viewcontroller class), and one doesn't (The pointer to my viewcontroller is strong, even though I name it as `weak`.

```
class MyViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    someOtherClass.function(someArgument) { [ weak myself = self ] in
    myself?.someButton.text = "I got you captured, Mr. ViewController"
}
```

The previous code succeeds in not letting someOtherClass point strongly to MyViewController. Then I take out the `weak myself = self` and name it in the function itself, like this:

```
class MyViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    someOtherClass.function(someArgument) {
    weak let myself = self
    myself?.someButton.text = "I got you captured, Mr. ViewController"
}
```

In this instance, someOtherClass points strongly to my viewController class. Anyone know why?

}

Comment: Sorry for the 3 quick edits in a row. Had to fix a bunch of stuff

Comment: If you want it to be a weak reference, why do you have `myself!` and not `myself?`?  Weak means it can go nil at any point.

Comment: You're right. I fixed it. But it's still pointing strongly to my ViewController

Comment: Yes.  Since you have `self` in the block of code you send to the other class it will capture your ViewController strongly.  If you want it to be weak, assign a weak variable outside of the function and use that weak variable inside the function.

Comment: ohhh, I'm an idiot. I see now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about scope of variable creation.  In your first example you are making a new variable (`weak myself`) in the scope of the ViewController class.  Then you pass that weak variable into the new class's function and do whatever you would like.

In your second example you are creating a new variable (`weak myself`) inside the function in the scope of the new class.  Since you create that variable in the new class using a strong referenced `self` you have a strong reference to your ViewController inside the new class.